# WebDriverWait is deprecated in Selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, selenium4

I'm getting a

> Warning: (143,13) 'WebDriverWait(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver, long)' is deprecated

in Selenium 4.0.0-alpha-3.

But official [Selenium page](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) lists only

```
WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepTimeOut)
```

as deprecated.

What is wrong? I'm using IntelliJ, could it be their issue?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It doesn't appear in the docs, but if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.java) you will see `@Deprecated` annotation

```
@Deprecated
public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeoutInSeconds) {
    this(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
}
```

In the constructor description you have the solution

> @deprecated Instead, use {@link
>   WebDriverWait#WebDriverWait(WebDriver, Duration)}.

Which is the constructor being called from the deprecated one in any case.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Answer (score 21):

Write it like this with Selenium 4 since what you tried to use is deprecated, as you said.

First import.

```
import java.time.Duration;

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
driver.manage().timeouts().scriptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
```

For fluent wait.

```
 Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

WebDriverWait statement

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Answer (score 9):

Code which gives the below warning:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Warning:

> The method `implicitlyWait(long, TimeUnit)` from the type `WebDriver.Timeouts` is deprecated.

Update which works on Selenium 4:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Use this instead. Only WebDriverWait(driver, clock) is supported;

Comment: no warning after using this in selenium version 4.0.0-alpha-7

Answer (score 3):

This warning message...

```
Warning: (143,13) 'WebDriverWait(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver, long)' is deprecated
```

...implies that the current constructor of [WebDriverWait](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) have been deprecated.

---

Looking in to the code for [WebDriverWait.java](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.java) it seems:

- The following methods are **deprecated**:
- `public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeoutInSeconds)`

  ```
       @Deprecated
       public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeoutInSeconds) {
         this(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
       }
  ```
- `public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeoutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)`

  ```
       @Deprecated
       public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeoutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis) {
         this(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutInSeconds), Duration.ofMillis(sleepInMillis));
       }
  ```
- `public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper, long timeoutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)`

  ```
       @Deprecated
       public WebDriverWait(
           WebDriver driver, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper, long timeoutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis) {
         this(
             driver,
             Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutInSeconds),
             Duration.ofMillis(sleepInMillis),
             clock,
             sleeper);
       }
  ```
- Whilst the following methods were **added**:
- `public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Duration timeout)`

  ```
       /**
        * @param driver The WebDriver instance to pass to the expected conditions
        * @param timeout The timeout when an expectation is called
        * @see WebDriverWait#ignoring(java.lang.Class)
        */
       public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Duration timeout) {
         this(
             driver,
             timeout,
             Duration.ofMillis(DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT),
             Clock.systemDefaultZone(),
             Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER);
       }
  ```
- `public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Duration timeout, Duration sleep)`

  ```
       /**
        * Wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered (thrown) by default in
        * the 'until' condition, and immediately propagate all others.  You can add more to the ignore
        * list by calling ignoring(exceptions to add).
        *
        * @param driver The WebDriver instance to pass to the expected conditions
        * @param timeout The timeout in seconds when an expectation is called
        * @param sleep The duration in milliseconds to sleep between polls.
        * @see WebDriverWait#ignoring(java.lang.Class)
        */
       public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Duration timeout, Duration sleep) {
         this(driver, timeout, sleep, Clock.systemDefaultZone(), Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER);
       }
  ```
- `WebDriver driver, Duration timeout, Duration sleep, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper)`

  ```
       /**
        * @param driver the WebDriver instance to pass to the expected conditions
        * @param clock used when measuring the timeout
        * @param sleeper used to make the current thread go to sleep
        * @param timeout the timeout when an expectation is called
        * @param sleep the timeout used whilst sleeping
        */
       public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Duration timeout, Duration sleep, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper) {
         super(driver, clock, sleeper);
         withTimeout(timeout);
         pollingEvery(sleep);
         ignoring(NotFoundException.class);
         this.driver = driver;
       }
  ```

Hence you see the error.

---

However, I don't see any changes to [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) Class in [**Selenium**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)**v4.0.0-alpha*** Java client changelog and the functionality should continue to function as per the current implementation.

#### Selenium Java client `v4.0.0-alpha-3` changelog:

```
v4.0.0-alpha-3
==============

* Add "relative" locators. The entry point is through the `RelativeLocator`.
  Usage is like `driver.findElements(withTagName("p").above(lowest));`
* Add chromedriver cast APIs to remote server (#7282)
* `By` is now serializable over JSON.
* Add ApplicationCache, Fetch, Network, Performance, Profiler,
  ResourceTiming, Security and Target CDP domains.
* Fixing Safari initialization code to be able to use Safari Technology
  Preview.
* Ensure that the protocol converter handles the new session responses
  properly.
* Expose devtools APIs from chromium derived drivers.
* Expose presence of devtools support on a role-based interface
* Move to new Grid, deleting the old standalone server and grid implementation.
* Switch to using `HttpHandler` where possible. This will impact projects that
  are extending Selenium Grid.
* Respect "webdriver.firefox.logfile" system property in legacy Firefox driver.
  Fixes #6649
* Back out OpenCensus support: OpenTracing and OpenCensus are merging, so
  settle on one for now.
* Only allow CORS when using a —allow-cors flag in the Grid server
* If you're using the Java Platform Module System, all modules
  associated with the project are generated as "open" modules. This
  will change in a future release.
* The version of Jetty being used is unshadowed.
```

---

### Conclusion

*Selenium's Java client v4.0.0-alpha-3* is still a *alpha* release and needs to go through *beta* release and hence shouldn't be used for testing activity in production environment.

---

### Solution

An immediate solution would be to downgrade to current **released level** [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet is working with Selenium 4.0:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Here which driver have to use for selenium 4? Earlier in selenium 3.141 version we have used `EventfiringWebDriver`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following lines of code:

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Use this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```

Basically, you are replacing the parameter and replacing two parameters (`30, TimeUnit.SECONDS`) with one (`Duration.ofSeconds(30)`)